# Automatically wrap long lines in Python code

Tags: windows, gratis, python, sublime-text

#### 1. Summary

I don't find, how I can automatically wrap long lines in `py` files. It would be nice, if someone tell me any command line or Sublime Text tool.

At the time I need to wrap long lines [**manually**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20873753/5951529).

#### 2. Argumentation

PEP8 E501 rule. Even if I set max line length, for example, to 120, some lines exceed the limit.

#### 3. Requirements

1. Windows 10 64-bit Enterprise LTSB EN,
2. Python 3.6.3,
3. Sublime Text, Build 3143.

#### 4. Example

My `SashaIsTheWorld.py` file:

```
amazing = True
spectacular = True
excellent = True
breathtaking = True
exciting = True
fantastic = True
unmatched = True
magnificent = True
breakneck = True
fascinating = True

if amazing and spectacular and excellent and breathtaking and exciting and fantastic and unmatched and magnificent and breakneck and fascinating is True:
    print("It about Sasha")
else:
    print("She's the one for me, She's my ecstasy, She's the one I need. She's one in a million, She's once in a lifetime, She made me discover one of the stars above us.")
```

```
D:\SashaPythonista>flake8 SashaIsTheWorld.py
SashaIsTheWorld.py:12:121: E501 line too long (153 > 120 characters)
SashaIsTheWorld.py:15:121: E501 line too long (177 > 120 characters)
```

#### 5. Expected behavior

For example:

```
amazing = True
spectacular = True
excellent = True
breathtaking = True
exciting = True
fantastic = True
unmatched = True
magnificent = True
breakneck = True
fascinating = True

if amazing and spectacular and excellent and breathtaking and exciting and fantastic \
        and unmatched and magnificent and breakneck and fascinating is True:
    print("It about Sasha")
else:
    print("She's the one for me, She's my ecstasy, She's the one I need. "
          "She's one in a million, She's once in a lifetime, She made me discover one of the stars above us.")
```

#### 6. Not helped

1. Google search,
2. For Python:

   1. [**autopep8**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8) with `--agressive` and `--experimental`,
   2. [**pyformat**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyformat).
3. For Sublime Text:

   1. [**AutoWrap**](https://github.com/randy3k/AutoWrap) not have “smart” wrapping. This package not add `\` symbol and additional quotes.
   2. [**Daniel Beck plugin**](https://superuser.com/a/469240/572069) also haven't “smart” wrapping.
   3. Sublime-Wrap-Plus works only [**for triple quoted strings**](https://github.com/ehuss/Sublime-Wrap-Plus#python-strings).
   4. [**WrapStatement**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/WrapStatement) not works for cases in my example.

#### 7. Do not offer

Please, don't tell, that:

1. I should not have long lines in the code,
2. I need to wrap all long lines manually,
3. I need to use [**ruler**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25901060/5951529). Yes, I use it.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, perhaps not an answer, as it points towards refactoring, rather than a tool to help wrap long lines.

If this is for work, then they should tell you how; if it is for private code, then don't sweat it, just have long lines if you want to.

That being said, long lines *are* a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Off the opt of my head, I can think of the following reasons for long lines (feel free to add more).

1. very long strings
2. deeply nested branching (many `if`s)
3. complicated conditionals (`if (A =B) and (V C> 123456) or (dictionary['key'] = 'value') or ....`

1) can be handled by manually breaking the long strings, of which I would not expect many.

2 & 3 both suggest refactoring ,and I see from your high rep on (Russian) Stack Overflow, that you ought to know about that :-)

For 1) some coding standards forbid besting conditionals more than X deep (my current company says 4, ymmv).  If there are many more, it might mean that the function is trying to do more than one thing - which is ***bad***

For 2 & 3, such complexity is better hidden in a function, and replaced by `if ConditionsValid():`

In both cases, we end up with (more) smaller functions, which are easier to read, maintain and unit test.

I am guessing that you know all of this, so am writing for other readers of the question.

Nevertheless, my recommendation is not to look for a tool which wraps long lines, but to ask yourself why you have so many longs lines (and to forgive yourself a few, if you can justify it).

You might also want to look (or ask) on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Please let me know what you think.